# ModernHttpClient in release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am using ModernHttpClient in my app (in PCL via nuget and the same version 2.0.1 in both Droid and IOS projects) and it works perfectly in Debug Mode. It also works for IOS in release mode but for Android I am getting exception saying Java.Net.SocketException (thrown from NativeMessageHandler some async method). Is there any setting needed for release mode? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was not because of ModernHttpClient but because the Internet permission was not set in the manifest file. It was working on Debug mode without this permission but not for Release mode.